# EF6 not loading all children

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have two entities Review and Competency. The review can have many competencies.

```
public class Review
{
    public int ReviewId {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Competency> Competencies {get; set;}
}

public class Competency
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int ReviewId {get; set;}
    public Review Review {get; set;}
}

public class MyContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Review> Reviews {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Competency> Compitencies {get; set;}
    
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Competency>().HasRequired(c => c.Review).WithMany(r =>   r.Competencies).HasForeignKey(c => c.ReviewId);
    }
}
```

Assume there are 3 competencies for reviewId 172. The below query will only return a review with the first competency.

```
Review review = _context.Reviews
                .Where(r => r.ReviewId == 172)                
                .Include(r => r.Competencies)
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

The generated SQL:

```
SELECT 
    [Project1].[ReviewId] AS [ReviewId], 
    [Project1].[ReviewPeriodId] AS [ReviewPeriodId], 
    [Project1].[ServiceNumber] AS [ServiceNumber], 
    [Project1].[ManagerServiceNumber] AS [ManagerServiceNumber], 
    [Project1].[ModeratorServiceNumber] AS [ModeratorServiceNumber], 
    [Project1].[ReviewStatusId] AS [ReviewStatusId], 
    [Project1].[IsLocked] AS [IsLocked], 
    [Project1].[DateCreated] AS [DateCreated], 
    [Project1].[AddedByServiceNumber] AS [AddedByServiceNumber], 
    [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Project1].[CompetencyId] AS [CompetencyId], 
    [Project1].[ReviewCompetency] AS [ReviewCompetency], 
    [Project1].[PerformanceStandard] AS [PerformanceStandard], 
    [Project1].[Remark] AS [Remark], 
    [Project1].[AddedByServiceNumber1] AS [AddedByServiceNumber1], 
    [Project1].[DateAdded] AS [DateAdded], 
    [Project1].[ReviewId1] AS [ReviewId1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ReviewId] AS [ReviewId], 
    [Extent1].[ReviewPeriodId] AS [ReviewPeriodId], 
    [Extent1].[ServiceNumber] AS [ServiceNumber], 
    [Extent1].[ManagerServiceNumber] AS [ManagerServiceNumber], 
    [Extent1].[ModeratorServiceNumber] AS [ModeratorServiceNumber], 
    [Extent1].[ReviewStatusId] AS [ReviewStatusId], 
    [Extent1].[IsLocked] AS [IsLocked], 
    [Extent1].[DateCreated] AS [DateCreated], 
    [Extent1].[AddedByServiceNumber] AS [AddedByServiceNumber], 
    [Extent2].[CompetencyId] AS [CompetencyId], 
    [Extent2].[ReviewCompetency] AS [ReviewCompetency], 
    [Extent2].[PerformanceStandard] AS [PerformanceStandard], 
    [Extent2].[Remark] AS [Remark], 
    [Extent2].[AddedByServiceNumber] AS [AddedByServiceNumber1], 
    [Extent2].[DateAdded] AS [DateAdded], 
    [Extent2].[ReviewId] AS [ReviewId1], 
CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[CompetencyId] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1]
FROM  [dbo].[Review] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Competency] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ReviewId] = [Extent2].[ReviewId]
WHERE [Extent1].[ReviewId] = 172)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[ReviewId] ASC, [Project1].[C1] ASC
```

The query results:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5euH1.png)

But EF6 only returns the first child (Competency):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPKxx.png)

I have used the include keyword as seen on my description, but I only get one competency entity. My expectation was that all 3 competencies should be returned.

Comment: i guess its because you are telling ef to only get the first Competencies. What if you remove the FirstOrDefault ?

Comment: There are other issues causes this problem. the code you sent here has no problem. I have tested it in a separated console application it worked fine.

Comment: As I can see, Review has no property named `ReviewId` but you wrote `_context.Reviews.Where(P => P.ReviewId = 172)` Its not possible with your models.

Comment: @RezaNoei Assume Id is ReviewId

Comment: So, source of the problem is somewhere else. this code works fine.

Comment: Please show the *exact* classes + mappings that cause this problem. You probably omitted some relevant details.

Comment: Double check that the DbContext is connecting to the expected database at runtime. Add  the following statement and a breakpoint to verify the connection string at runtime: `var connectionString = _context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString;` (EF6) Often issues like come up when developers change connection details and the application is left connecting to an older copy of a database.